# Fake LogIn page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to create fake login page with jQuery - purely for testing/template presentation purposes.

What form should do(see details in .js code):

*Correct email: admin@admin.com / pass: admin*

- check the values of the #username & #password against values in the .js
- if return true for both values alert    'valid' and go to  home.html
- if not    valid alert 'not valid' and display    the error msg

**Code at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/ZYZPY/**

**HTML**

```
<form class="loginbox" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
        <p style="display: none;" class="error">Error. Please enter correct email &amp; password.</p>
        <label for="username">E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <label for="username">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="LOG IN" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').focus();

    $('#submit').click(function() {

        event.preventDefault(); // prevent PageReLoad
        $('.error').css('display', 'none'); // hide error msg

        var ValEmail = $('#username').val('admin@admin.com'); // Email Value
        var ValPassword = $('#password').val('admin'); // Password Value

        if (ValEmail === true & ValPassword === true) { // if ValEmail & ValPass are as above
            alert('valid!'); // alert valid!
            window.location = "home.html"; // go to home.html
        }
        else {
            alert('not valid!'); // alert not valid!
            $('.error').css('display', 'block'); // show error msg
        }
    });
});
```

**At the moment form always return else = false - why??**

Any help much appreciated!
Pete

---

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/ZYZPY/12/**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (ValEmail === true & ValPassword === true) {
```

Should be `&&` instead of `&`
And `val` is used to get the value of input, you should:

```
var ValidEmail = $('#username').val() === 'admin@admin.com'; // Email validate
var ValidPassword = $('#password').val() === 'admin'; // Password validate

if (ValidEmail === true && ValidPassword === true) { // if ValidEmail & ValidPassword
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTGt9/

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Another quick one - how can I clear the form after click event?

Comment: Sorry Guys, assuming you all using Chrome as this does not work on IE8 either the FF4.

Comment: @Pete Just change $('#submit').click(function() to $('#submit').click(function(**event**)

Answer (score 2):

use something like, val with param will set value

```
var ValEmail = $('#username').val()=='admin@admin.com';
var ValPassword = $('#password').val()=='admin';
```

Also the  && operator instead of & as mentioned

Also I see event is not defined.?

Answer (score 0):

Event was not defined.

It needs to be passed via the method of Click event.

Example:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();   });
```